# r package development imports not loaded

Tags: r, dependencies, package

Hi I am new to writing R packages.

I try to import dependencies via:

```
Imports: forecast, ggplot2, dplyr
```

When I click Build & Reload in Rstudio my library is built successfully. However when checking if the dependencies are loaded for real Rstudio tells me that they are not.
In my namespaces file I only have

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

Is it a problem that there is no specific import of namespaces like in https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/NAMESPACE

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the imports to the `NAMESPACE`. The `Imports` tag in `DESCRIPTION` just lists the packages that the `NAMESPACE` references for imports that aren't listed in the `Depends` tag.

To import everything exported from the three packages you list, add the following to your `NAMESPACE`

```
import(forecast, ggplot2, dplyr)
```

It is generally not advisable to just blanket import from packages. You should be selective and import only those functions that your package needs. You do that via `importFrom()`.

For more details, see [Section 1.5.1 in Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports).

It might be worth using **roxygen2** to manage this for you, which you do via the `@import` tag (in the R code in `#'` roxygen comments, not in `DESCRIPTION`). See the documentation for that package and [Hadley Wickham's R Packages book (online version)](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html)

Comment: So if I understand roxygen2 documentation correctly I would need to put #' @import forecast  before a function declaration to import a whole package?

Comment: Yes, but don't import the whole thing. You'll thank me later.

Comment: ...so do `#' @importFrom` for the stuff you actually use in the function.

Comment: What @joran said (I didn't want to turn this into a rehash of the roxygen documentation or Hadley's book as it wasn't clear to me your question was even about roxygen)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Maybe you can help me here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720340/r-package-development-function-not-exported-to-opencpu --> my simple function is exported via roxygen2 however opencpu does not recognize the function