# r package development - own function not visible for opencpu

Tags: r, namespaces, package, opencpu

Hi I am new to writing R packages.

[r package development imports not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719243/r-package-development-imports-not-loaded/30719420?noredirect=1#comment49496500_30719420) advised me to use roxygen2.
I once called `devtools::document()` and the namespace was generated.

However when I load this simple package (or try it via opencpu) the functions are NOT available.

calling the code in native R seems to work

```
test2::hello()
[1] "Hello, world!"
```

Starting opencpu like:

1) start opencpu simple server via `library(opencpu)`

2) execute `opencpu$restart`which will show a port number

3) http://localhost:myPortNumber/ocpu/library/myPackage/info ---> this endpoint works

As mentioned in the comments this is not a "proper" way of calling a function. However opencpu defaults to `myfunction/print` if a function is called via HTTP as `http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/stats/R/quantile/print`and even that does not work when I call the hello function.

This is a demonstration of how to call a more complex function:

```
curl http://localhost:myPortNumber/ocpu/library/stats/R/quantile/json -d '{"type":1,"x":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],"probs":[0.05,0.25,0.75,0.95]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

You can simply test it via:

```
curl http://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/stats/R/quantile/json -d \
'{"type":1,"x":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],"probs":[0.05,0.25,0.75,0.95]}' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I did install it via sudo like:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL test2_0.1.tgz
```

that means it should be available via in the `/library/test2` endpoint.

## Solution:

It still was the wrong API endpoint --> I was missing the R sub-directory

```
http://localhost:myPort/ocpu/library/myPackage/R/hello/
```

Example-code is here: https://github.com/geoHeil/rSimplePackageForOpenCpu

Comment: Is that how you call a function with openCPU? It seems to be looking for a file. You seem to be conflating things here. Either it is or it is not exported. Limit the scope of the question to calling some function from a package in openCPU.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/remotely-use-r-packages-on-github/): For an R package to be used remotely on OpenCPU, it must be installible with `install_github` and the R package name must be identical to the repository name. I.e. if this works on your local machine:

Comment: Two things to know: (a) opencpu has its own library, perhaps under `/usr/lib/opencpu/library/` for packages; and (b) it does not look in a personal library, often a requirement for linux-based *R* users. Check `attr(packageDescription('test2'), 'file')` to see if it's installed in a location that opencpu knows about (i.e., *not* in your homedir).

Comment: @GavinSimpson: that is a correct endpoint for opencpu, assuming that the package is installed (correctly). The first directory under `/ocpu/library/` is the library name, the "file" in this directory is the function itself.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: opencpu *can* see userdirs, if setup properly, via `/ocpu/user/{username}/library/{pkgname}/`. (Huh, never used that before ...) (Reference: [opencpu api](https://www.opencpu.org/api.html#api-libraries).)

Comment: You are right. However I installed into the global directory vis sudo. Regarding calling the function I will update the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still was the wrong API endpoint --> I was missing the R sub-directory

```
http://localhost:myPort/ocpu/library/myPackage/R/hello/
```